# Process a value before displaying it with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, enums

I have a controller that update a value according to a radiobuttons list.

```
MyTypes = {
    "cat": 0,
    "dog": 1,
    "cow": 2
};

function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.value= 1;     //Updated by a radiobuttons list
}

<!-- Display -->
<label >Type ({{value}})</label>
```

This would display "1". I would like to display "dog". Is there a way to call a function inside the html template? This function would find the key associated to value.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing it like this:

```
[snip MyTypes setup]
function MyController($scope) {
    var typesById = [];
    angular.forEach(MyTypes,function(v,k){typesById[+k]=v;});
    $scope.typesById=typesById;
    $scope.value= 1;     //Updated by a radiobuttons list
}

<!-- Display -->
<label >Type ({{typesById[value]}})</label>
```